# Sequelize bulkUpdate & get affected rows

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using 'bulkCreate' with 'updateOnDuplicate' option to achieve bulkUpdate, like this:

```
Product.bulkCreate(to_update, {
  updateOnDuplicate: ['name', 'description'],
});
```

It works fine, but I can't find a way to get the affected rows count.
I tried adding 'updatedAt' to the fields to update and then counting the rows where 'updatedAt' is greater than the time before starting the execution. But ended up with all rows receiving CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as 'updatedAt'.

I'm sure this is a standard requirement, but then again, so is the 'bulkUpdate'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and this is the function I ended up writing

```
async function bulkCreate({ model, where, data, options }) {

  const beforeCount = await model.count({ where });
  const updateInfo = await model.bulkCreate(data, options);
  const afterCount = await model.count({ where });

  const hasChanges = updateInfo.some(row => row.changed());
  const hasNew = beforeCount !== afterCount;

  return { changed: hasChanges || hasNew };
}
```

I think the code explains itself pretty well.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get the number of created records from the `bulkCreate` function. I tried several approaches that I found online and none worked - I think there might be a way if you're using a database-determined primary key, but my primary key is data-derived. So this code just counts the number of items before and after - it requires that you provide a `where` clause that will capture all the data you may or may not be adding; coming up with that clause was trivial in my case.

`bulkCreate` does has an easy way to find rows that have been changed, so I used that here.